# Accepting a Freelancer project

Tags: freelance-websites, negotiation

I've been offered a project on Freelancer, but I don't know how to accept it. How do I accept the job and start working on it?

This is the email that I received:

[image]

Comment: You seem to be offering yourself your own job in that notification? Are you trying to dishonestly improve your own profile standing. You are never going to get away with that.

Comment: I would suggest that for answers about how to use freelancer, the best place to ask would be Freelancer themselves.

Comment: Just to get the obvious out of the way: this SE site is about freelancing in general, aka working independent. Not the website.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are the one who offered the project to the freelancer. Now you have to wait for the freelancer to accept the job. Then you will get another notification email. You can proceed from there.